# Как вывести все данные из x-data в отдельную функцию?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Я недавно начал изучать Alpine.js и узнал, что можно выводить все данные из x-data в отдельную функцию. Я попытался вывести данные из случайной формы из интернета, но у меня почему-то не получилось, появлялись ошибки.

```
x-data="select({ data: { group1: "group1", group2: "group2", group3: "group3", group4: "group4"}, emptyOptionsMessage: "group not found", name: "group", placeholder: "select a group" })"
```

Comment: В каком смысле _«выводить данные из x-data»_? В атрибут `x-data` данные обычно **вводят**, а не выводят что-то из него... Сформулируй задачу из вопроса более внятно, пожалуйста. И добавь код реализации функции `select` - чтобы общая логика была яснее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, поможет пример обратной операции: *ввода* данных в `x-data` из результата функции:

```js
const foo = () => ({
  greeting: 'Hello, stackoverflow!',
  counter: 0,
  btnStyle: { width: '2.5em', height: '2.5em', fontSize: '1.2rem', borderRadius: '50%' },
  items: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
});
```

```html
<div x-data="foo()">
  <h4 x-text="greeting"></h4>
  <button x-text="counter" :style="btnStyle" @click="++counter"></button>
  <ul>
    <template x-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
      <li x-text="item"></li>
    </template>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
```

Что касается *вывода* данных: в документации библиотеки я не нашел такой возможности, но через devtools браузера можно обнаружить у DOM-объекта элемента (того, что с атрибутом `x-data`) свойство `_x_dataStack`, которое является массивом... и в моем случае, объект данных оказался в его первом элементе (`_x_dataStack[0]`). Но насколько постоянным является такое поведение, и почему используется массив (в нем только одно значение) - мне неизвестно. Такой способ доступа хакообразен, и поэтому рекомендую использовать его только для какой-либо отладки через консоль, но не более того.

Comment: Спасибо! По вашему примеру я смог выполнить ввод данных в `x-data` из результата функции:

`let select = () => select({
 data: { group1: "group1", group2: "group2", group3: "group3", group4: "group4"},
 emptyOptionsMessage: "group not found",
 name: "group",
 placeholder: "select a group" })`

Comment: @Logos, все равно я не понял в чем была задача :D ну да не суть - главное что получилось, а ответ оба варианта закрывает хотя бы частично)) Кстати, осторожнее с применением Alpine в продакшн целях - вчера я с удивлением обнаружил, что библиотечка без полифиллов ломается в старых браузерах, в частности в легаси сборках хромиума (Kiwi браузер, если о чем-то говорит). Раньше вроде не ломалась, видать попортили ее... с маленькими проектами так бывает.